# Stanford CoreNLP server not responding

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have been trying to use the CoreNLP server using various python packages including [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html). I am always running into the same problem that I do not hear back from the server. So I instead looked up as to how I can test the original server based on the documentation.

I downloaded a copy of CoreNLP from the [website](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html). I then try to start a server from the terminal and go to my localhost as described [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#getting-started). 
Based on the documentation I should see something when I go to http://localhost:9000/, but nothing loads up.

Here are to commands I use:

```
cd stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Here is the output of running the commands above:

```
[main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - setting default constituency parser
[main] INFO CoreNLP - warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
[main] INFO CoreNLP - using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead
[main] INFO CoreNLP - to use shift reduce parser download English models jar from:
[main] INFO CoreNLP - http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
[main] INFO CoreNLP -     Threads: 8
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

I then go to http://localhost:9000/, nothing loads up. Like I mentioned above originally I have been trying to do the same thing using some of the python packages and observed similar behavior.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961208/stanfordcorenlp-server-listening-indefinitely-using-stanza) is a stack overflow post related to server not responding using Stanza.

OS: MacOS 10.15.4
Python: 3.7.7
Java: 1.8

Could it an issue with Java version? Or with the model I downloaded from the website?